# Setting a vector<vector<double>::iterator>

Tags: c++, vector

Apologies in advance, I am relatively new to C++ and was handed down some code that I'm trying to make heads or tails of.

The code is creating a `vector<vector<double>::iterator>` of a defined size and then assigning it `.end()` from another `vector` that's being created like so...

```
vector<vector<double>::iterator> treatment_begin(50), treatment_end(50);

for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i){
       treatment_begin[i] = treatment_sorted.end();
       treatment_sorted.push_back(values_vector[i]);
       treatment_end[i] = treatment_sorted.end();
}
```

So it's, as best I understand, setting on iterator then adding a value to the vector and setting another iterator. But I am running into problems where the last iterator of `treatment_end` is something like -9.7458369411281581e+297 and then later on the code is trying to use that `treatment_end` iterator and blowing up like so...

```
treatment_left.insert(treatment_left.end(),treatment_begin[49],treatment_end[49] );
```

Specifically its giving a 'vector iterators in range are different from containers'. I am guessing the problem is not the insert itself at the end but how treatment_end is being built in the first code block. Sorry again if this is a dumb question I just can't wrap my head around where this code is wrong and what the proper approach should be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "was handed down some code that I'm trying to make heads or tails of" whoever handed this code down to you should be the recipient of a strongly worded letter, or perhaps a horse head under their sheets.

Comment: Storing iterators that live longer than a local variable is a tricky thing, most especially with `vector` iterators. If you need to fix this code, probably switching from iterators to numeric indices would be the way to go. In some places, this might also require adding references or pointers to the `vector` they index into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been given code that has undefined behaviour.

Every element of `treatment_begin`, and all but the last element of `treatment_end` are invalid iterators. They do not point to elements of `treatment_sorted`

[`std::vector<T>::push_back( const T& value );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators
>   and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Even if you did all the insertions into `treatment_sorted`, there is no "before-the-start" iterator to go in `treatment_begin[0]`.

You will need to go back to the original author to find out what this is *meant* to do.

Comment: Thanks, this was unfortunately the answer I was expecting. Original author is long gone. I am honestly not sure the intention of the code, its a conversion of an R script I've also never seen and I'm afraid of changing too much and thus altering the outcomes it generates. Thank you anyway.